# Rotating image not smooth anim

Tags: html, css, animation

I tried to create this animation so the image would tilt from left to the right and vice-versa, but as you can see in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzm8wc1f/5/) it's not smooth for some reason. It tilts weirdly.

```css
@keyframes cat {
  0%{
   transform:rotate(0deg);
  }

  33%{
 transform:rotate(-5deg);
  }

  66%{
  transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  100%{
  transform:rotate(5deg);
  }
}

img{
  margin:32px 0px 0px 32px;
  animation:cat 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start for -5deg then go to 5deg and then return again to -5deg:

```css
@keyframes cat {
  0%{
   transform:rotate(-5deg);
  }

  50%{
   transform:rotate(5deg);
  }
  
  100%{
   transform:rotate(-5deg);
  }
}

img{
  margin:32px 0px 0px 32px;
  animation:cat 0.5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @VGO Exclusive, please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: yeah had to wait for stackoverflow to allow me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to shake the picture you can use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/akash_dutta/yzm8wc1f/24/)

```
@keyframes cat {
  0%{
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }

  10%{
        transform:rotate(-5deg);
  }
   20%{
        transform:rotate(5deg);
  }
   30%{
        transform:rotate(-5deg);
  }
   40%{
        transform:rotate(5deg);
  }
   50%{
        transform:rotate(-5deg);
  }

  60%{
        transform:rotate(5deg);
  }
   70%{
        transform:rotate(-5deg);
  }
   80%{
        transform:rotate(5deg);
  }
   90%{
        transform:rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100%{
        transform:rotate(5deg);
  }
}

img{
  margin:32px 0px 0px 32px;
    animation:cat 1s infinite;
}
```

Or else if you want a smooth transition use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/akash_dutta/yzm8wc1f/30/)

```
@keyframes cat {
  0%{
    transform:rotate(-10deg);
  }

  50%{
        transform:rotate(10deg);
  }
  100%{
        transform:rotate(-10deg);
  }
}

img{
  margin:32px 0px 0px 32px;
    animation:cat 1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: .19,.83,.91,.31;
}
```

animation time function is nothing but defines how your element will move with time
Some default time constant is linear, ease-in, ease-out, ease-in-out,
But you can create custom time function in http://cubic-bezier.com.
Hope this was helpful.